# Could you help me to optimize sql query db2

Tags: sql, optimization, db2

Could you help me to optimize this query:

```
select distinct PUBLSEQ from PUBLCOVER P
          WHERE EXISTS
          ( SELECT * FROM PUBLCOVER A, COVERAREA B, PRODCODEDICT C
            WHERE A.PUBLSEQ = P.PUBLSEQ
            AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
            AND A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
            AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
            AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
            AND C.STATUS = 'A'
            AND A.COVAREA = 1823
            )
          AND NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT * FROM PUBLCOVER A, COVERAREA B, PRODCODEDICT C
            WHERE A.PUBLSEQ = P.PUBLSEQ
            AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
            AND A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
            AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
            AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
            AND C.STATUS = 'A'
            AND A.COVAREA NOT IN (1823, 34)
            )
```

I would like to escape from `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, leaving only one.

Comment: You're asking for A.COVAREA = 1823 and also NOT NOT 1823 or 34. Isn't that the same as A.COVAREA = 1823 and (1823 or 34). which is the same as 1823? In other words, does the second EXISTS actually do anything?

Comment: @MichaelY. Presumably there are multiple records for a given value of `PUBLSEQ`, so the `EXISTS` is ensuring that at least one occurrence has a `COVAREA` value of `1823`, and the `NOT EXISTS` is ensuring that all occurrences are either `1823` or `34`.  Or maybe I'm just tired.

Comment: Does your query actually return anything except 1823?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to eliminate both and simply use conditional aggregates in the `HAVING` clause, something like:

```
SELECT A.PUBLSEQ
FROM PUBLCOVER A
    JOIN  COVERAREA B
    ON A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
    JOIN  PRODCODEDICT C
    ON B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
WHERE A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
    AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
    AND C.STATUS = 'A'
GROUP BY A.PUBLSEQ
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN A.COVAREA NOT IN (1823, 34) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
  AND  MAX(CASE WHEN A.COVAREA = 1823 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Might need to move `WHERE` criteria to the conditional aggregate(s), something like this:

```
SELECT A.PUBLSEQ
FROM PUBLCOVER A
    JOIN  COVERAREA B
    ON A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
    JOIN  PRODCODEDICT C
    ON B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
GROUP BY A.PUBLSEQ
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN A.COVAREA NOT IN (1823, 34)
                 AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
                 AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
                 AND C.STATUS = 'A' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) = 0
  AND  MAX(CASE WHEN A.COVAREA = 1823  AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
                 AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
                 AND C.STATUS = 'A' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END) = 1
```

You've not provided enough in your question to know exactly what you need, but the above two suggestions are close.

Comment: It returns a different result. It's not the same result as my query

Comment: @Telal  What's it returning incorrectly?  I'm guessing you'll need to move some of the `WHERE` criteria into the conditional criteria, but there's not enough info in your question to know.  Also I had one errant line in the `WHERE` I just removed, but it shouldn't have run with that in there.

Comment: It just return different A.PUBLSEQ. The result isn't corrent

Comment: @Telal You've not given enough to help you further.  Did you try moving criteria from `WHERE` into the conditional logic in the `HAVING`?  Updated answer with a sample of what that would look like, can't help beyond that.

Comment: sorry)  It's not the same result as my query again

Comment: @Telal You'll have to do the work to figure out why and tweak accordingly since you haven't provided enough information.  The point is that you can use conditional aggregates in `HAVING` to improve your query.